# Android AsyncTask and Mockito (or PowreMockito)

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-asynctask, mockito

I have a configuration manager that retrieves a json from a remote server. Then it is parsed into a ConfigWrapper object and that object gets returned as a parameter in a provided Callback listener.

So in the test class I call:

```
@Test
public void init_Configuration_With_Network_Load_JSON_From_Server_Return_To_Listener() {

    mockConnectivityCheck(true);

    ...

    mManager.initConfiguration(mContext, eq(anyString()), mListener);

    verify(mListener, times(1)).onConfigurationLoaded(any(ConfigWrapper.class));

}
```

mContext is mocked and mListener is also mocked.
This will call the class under test's method:

```
    public void initConfiguration(Context context, String url, ConfigurationManagerListener listener){
        // Get a reference to shared preferences
        mSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // If we have network, we should load configurations from remote, otherwise, try to load it from assets folder OR shared pref
        if (NetworkTools.hasNetworkConnection(context)){
            getConfigurationRemote(context, url, listener);
        } else {
            getConfigurationOffline(context, listener);
        }
    }
```

So if we have network, we can get the configuration from the server.
This method does it:

```
private void getConfigurationRemote(final Context context, String url, final ConfigurationManagerListener
        listener) {

    // Send a request to get the configuration
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, HashMap<String, Object>> () {

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStream in = null;
            HashMap result = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                in = conn.getInputStream();
                result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(in, HashMap.class);
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (in != null){
                        in.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> config) {

            // We if have a valid result, save the data to shared pref AND save it to a ConfigurationWrapper object
            // other wise, try to load from assets folder or shared pref if available
            if (config != null && config.size() > 0){

                // We want to save the hierarchy of the JSON so we save its string representation to shared pref
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(config);
                mSharedPref.edit().putString(CONFIGURATIONS_KEY, object.toString()).apply();
                mConfigurationWrapper = new ConfigWrapper(config);
                listener.onConfigurationLoaded(mConfigurationWrapper);
            } else {
                // No valid configuration from remote server, so load it from local source
                getConfigurationOffline(context, listener);
            }
        }

    }.execute(url);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to write a unit test using Mockito (or PowerMockito if needed) that can test this code. 
I'm not entirely sure how to tackle this situation where I call a method that has a new AsyncTask().execute() call in it.
So far, calling the initConfiguration method and mocking the network check to return true, stops after calling execute(). doInBackground() does not seem to get called.

How would you test such code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way your code is set up makes unit testing hard. I'd suggest rearranging it.

The getConfigurationRemote method currently does 3 separate things:

- creates the `AsyncTask`
- defines what that task does
- executes the task

My solution:

- move the anonymous `AsyncTask` to its own class.
- move the creation of the task (`new AsyncTask(....`) to a factory class or, better yet, use a dependency injection framework like [Dagger](https://github.com/square/Dagger).

This is how i imagine it to look like in the end:

```
private void getConfigurationRemote(final Context context, String url, final ConfigurationManagerListener listener) {
    // create the task
    ConfigurationRemoteAsyncTask task = taskFactory.createConfigurationRemoteTask(listener);
    // Send a request to get the configuration
    task.execute(url);
}
```

Now you can mock and test much more easily:

- verify that task.execute is called with the given url when .initConfiguration is called by simply mocking the task returned by the task factory.
- verify that listener.onConfigurationLoaded is called when task.onPostExecute is called, without mocking the whole network infrastructure. This might look like this:

  ```
  @Test
  public void init_Configuration_With_Network_Load_JSON_From_Server_Return_To_Listener() {
      ConfigurationRemoteAsyncTask task = new ConfigurationRemoteAsyncTask(mockedListener);
      HashMap<String, Object> config = getNotEmptyConfig();
      task.onPostExecute(config);
      verify(mockedListener).onConfigurationLoaded(any(ConfigWrapper.class));
  }
  ```

Comment: OO thanks for the reply!
task.onPostExecute provides a parameter. The actual result I received from the server. I assume I will be able to call task.onPostExecute(some hashmap) and then verify the expected behaviour correct?
And just to understand fully could you please add how the test method itself might be written?
I assume I need to get the AsyncTask from the factory class and simply call its onPostExecute method right?

Comment: @AlonMinski I've added an example test. Yes, you call onPostExecute with a non-empty map and then verify the expected behaviour. I'm not using the task factory in the unit tests of the task itself though since i only want to test the behaviour of the task itself.

Comment: Brilliant. This helped a lot! Thanks.